# Raspberry Pi で espeak を実行すると ALSA がエラーを出す

Tags: raspberry-pi

下記サイトを参考にespeakを入れたのですがエラーが発生しました。
https://qiita.com/PonDad/items/c5419c164b4f2efee368

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping
unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping
unlock
```

調べてもいまいち解決方法がわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

#### 環境

- 外付けスピーカーにつなげています。
- espeak 1.48.04
- Raspbian 9.4
- tensorflow 1.4.1
- keras 2.1.2

Comment: お使いの機器には音声出力が備わっていますか？　espeak をインストールしようとしている環境の情報（OSなど）を追記してください。

Comment: 外付けスピーカーにつなげています。環境はespeak 1.48.04、Raspbian 9.4、tensorflow 1.4.1、keras 2.1.2です。

Comment: おそらくサウンドデバイスが上手く認識されていないのだと思います。スピーカーをつなげた状態で、`aplay -l` の実行結果を本文に追記して頂けませんか？　本文下の「編集」から自由に追記できます。

Comment: 上手く認識されていなかったようです。再度インストールしたら普通に音声が出ました。

Answer (score 1):

[ALSA](http://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0177) 関連のエラーが出ているので、おそらくサウンドデバイスが上手く認識されていないのだと思います。以下のことをお確かめください。

- スピーカーがちゃんと物理的に接続されているか。
- ALSA などのソフトウェアからスピーカーが認識されているか。たとえば `aplay -l` を実行すると、認識されているデバイスの一覧を見ることができます。
- デフォルトの再生デバイスがそのスピーカーになっているか。なっていない場合、`~/.asoundrc` というファイルを弄るなどして対応することになります。

### 追記

[質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/28049/tokoroten)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43018/raspberry-pi-%E3%81%A7-espeak-%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-alsa-%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99?noredirect=1#comment44520_43018)より:

> 上手く認識されていなかったようです。再度インストールしたら普通に音声が出ました。